# phone has better wifi than usb adapter

Tags: wireless-networking

strangely, an iphone 11 reaches 100 Mbit/s while a usb wifi adapter (TP-Link Archer T3U Plus AC1300) barely gets 20 Mbit/s, both of them are tested at the same location and the same wifi. I highly suspect that the adapter is defective.
just to clear, the problem is that why the phone has better speed than the usb adapter, logically the adapter has an antenna so it should be the one with the better wifi speed. I installed the driver from the official website, so that leaves only a problem with the adapter itself being defective, do you agree with me or you think it could be another thing. 
edit : I tested the adapter with another pc and I got 70 Mbit/s, so the adapter with pc-1 gives me 20 Mbit/s and with pc-2 it gives me 70 Mbit/s (both pcs are in the same location), is there any setting that could make this adapter behave like this on pc-1

Comment: There is a download for the [Archer T3U V1 driver](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t3u/) that you could try to install.

Comment: @Mokubai yes I use a usb3 port

Comment: And your computer has enough RAM, is not running high CPU doing other things, isn't using the HDD all the time? Basically the system is not heavily loaded system with any resource at 100%... Also is the antenna is properly connected?

Comment: @Mokubai, I tested the adapter fresh after the pc starts, the pc has 16gb ram and ssd, for the antenna it comes attached to the adapter it is not detachable.

Comment: Does pc-1 have a Bluetooth connection? E.g. a mouse/keyboard or something? I believe Bluetooth can interfer with Wifi.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke no pc-1 has no Bluetooth connection, pc-2 was tested right next to pc-1, it is so strange now hhh.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there is a huge misconception about the way wifi speeds are calculated, for your device and the router to communicate at the optimal speed a lot of requirement must be met, beyond the advertised speed, like the actual band your going to use (5ghz or 2,4ghz), the wifi channel width, the MIMO config, and a lot more.

If you find your self in a situation like this: "You have 1 Gbps Internet, and just bought a very expensive AX11000 class router with advertised speeds of up to 11 Gbps, but when you run a speed test from your iPhone XS Max (at a distance of around 32 feet), you only get around 450 Mbps (±45 Mbps). Same for iPad Pro. Same for Samsung Galaxy S8. Same for a laptop computer. Same for most wireless clients. Why? Because that is the speed expected from these (2×2 MIMO) devices! This section explains in great detail exactly why that is." then this article is for you https://www.duckware.com/tech/wifi-in-the-us.html